# Sending parameters with file - Delivery.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, file-upload, socket.io

I'm trying to upload a file using nodejs,socket.io and delivery.js. The file upload is working fine for me, but I need to send some parameters with the file.But I don't see how I can do that! Here's my code so far.

Client.html

```
var socket = io.connect();

  var delivery = new Delivery(socket);

  function sendFile(){

    delivery.on('delivery.connect',function(delivery){

        var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
        var extraParams = {foo: 'bar'};
        delivery.send(file, extraParams); //trying to send the params with file
        return false;
    });

    delivery.on('send.success',function(fileUID){
      alert("file was successfully sent.");
    });

  }
```

and my server.js

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  var delivery = dl.listen(socket);
  delivery.on('receive.success',function(file){
  // delivery.on('receive.success',function(file,params){<--tried this also

    var params = file.params;
    console.log(params);
    fs.writeFile(file.name,file.buffer, function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log('File could not be saved.');
      }else{
        console.log('File saved.');
      };
    });
  });
});
```

But my `console.log(params)` prints `undefined`. I would be really grateful if anyone could point me to the right direction.

**Update**: Solved the issue by cloning from github deliver.js,the npmjs code seems to be outdated.